# What is the suitable optimization method for this case?

Tags: integer-programming, machine-learning, gurobipy, deep-learning

What is the best optimization method to solve a large-scale problem (about 300 thousand variables)?

The problem is nonlinear, nonconvex, involves only binary variables, and is unconstrained. The objective function is expressed as a large-scale neural network.

Comment: That might be an extraordinarily difficult problem to solve. https://yalmip.github.io/slowmilp .

Comment: You could try local search - I've used it to deal with 500k non-binary variables in a single unpartitioned dataset - but the objective function needs to be fast enough, or this approach will fail. I doubt that's the case here. For local search, your objective function should return in less than 100 microseconds, so you can it 10k times per second. A large-scale neural network normally takes longer.

Comment: Does the objective function have any specific structure that perhaps could be exploited? For instance, is it a polynomial?

Comment: @prubin Thank you. The objective function is nonlinear as it comes from the neural network structure.

Comment: The NN consumes 30 seconds that is the challenge I have @GeoffreyDeSmet

Comment: Why not use the typical stochastic batch training for your NN?

Comment: Thank you @ Brannon. The NN is already trained. The objective function in my problem is calcauted using this NN which consumes 30 second to return the output.

Comment: @HusseinSharadga 30 seconds for a single objective function run? Local Search won't work. You want that 300k times faster to run in a minute. Or run for 208 days, which is not realistic in practice.

Comment: Some additional snippet description of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: @ Matheus Diógenes Andrade

Thank you. I have an image with dimensions of 512 x 512 pixels. I need to generate the best mask for the picture, assigning a 0 or 1 value to each pixel. I evaluate the mask using a pre-trained neural network (NN), which takes 30 seconds to process due to the substantial size of the NN.